# PHP Question - How to stop users from navigating to other pages by changing the URL

Tags: php

I have a resetpwd.php page that is shown when a user's password is reset in the database.  However, this page can be accessed by users whose password is not reset by manually changing the URL to "/resetpwd.php".  How can I prevent this?

Comment: Why is it a problem that users can access that page?

Comment: Why should the users be able to access that page if they did not request a password reset?

Comment: why not? As long as no password is actually changed, what's the harm?

Comment: @Olimicus03 If the page isn't a heavy resource drain (which I imagine it shouldn't be if it's just a "your password was reset" confirmation), you are likely going to spend more resources on prevention than you would by just letting people see it.  In the long run you may end up adding extra code and overhead that is simply unnecessary in your attempt to fix a nonexistent problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really possible to prevent changing the URL, because the HTTP server does not really care if the URL was clicked on a page that you provided to the user, or typed in the browser's location bar.

Instead, add some code to `resetpwd.php` to check if the user accessing it is allowed to do so, i.e. if his password is reset in the database. If not, just `exit` the script or redirect the user to a different page.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply prevent people from accessing it by typing in the URL.  The best you could do would be to set a flag when a user's password is reset and redirect users whose accounts aren't flagged.

It may be worth considering why you need to "hide" this page from users.  For example, you can navigate directly to https://stackoverflow.com/error.  Looking at that page doesn't mean an actual server error occurred, but you should be intuitively aware of this if you intentionally type in that URL.

Answer (score 1):

**Negative answer is a legitimate answer too**. Leave it alone.

Noway.
Just leave it alone. there is no reason in preventing access to this page.

Comment: Well, there *shouldn't* be any reason to prevent access to this page. If there is, you have a design error...

Answer (score -1):

depends how the user gets to that page.
On a part of mine I had this idea:

---

```
if($_SESSION['userid'] != $_GET['id'])
{
//check if user if signed in
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == true)
  {
        //unset all variables
        $_SESSION['signed_in'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['user_id']   = NULL;
    echo 'Error';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Por favor, log in again. Gracias.';
  }
echo '<script type="text/javascript">self.close();</script>';
die();
}
```

---

if someone wants to get to this page, which contains private data, I just compare the userid with the session user_id and if they are not equal (an user is trying to get into thru browser side) I log him off and close the window with a javascript line and abort everything else.

Comment: it's reset password page. it is implied that user CANNOT log in if they have to use this service